# Is there any better way to IntrinsicAttributes & TYPE in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, intrinsicattributes

This code is works good.

```
<AuctionCardGenerator auction={auction} />;
```

```
interface auctionType {
    auction: randomAuctionType;
}

const AuctionCardGenerator = ({ auction }: auctionType) => {
...
}
```

and randomAuctionType is looks this.

```
interface randomAuctionType {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    artist: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        nickname: string;
    };
    type: string;
    price: string;
    description: string;
    status: AUCTION_STATE;
    nftToken?: string;
    imgSrc: string;
}
```

But I think that declaring auctionType just for this code isn't efficient.
So I want to use just like bellow.

```
const AuctionCardGenerator = (auction: randomAuctionType) => {
```

But this code has error message like this
[image]

So, Is there any simple way to avoid this problem in typescript?

Comment: "*I think that declaring `auctionType` just for this code isn't efficient.*" - what kind of "efficiency" are you thinking of here?

Comment: I think declaring a new interface isn't looks good. It doesn't used in another code.
I just thought there could be better way for this code

Comment: pls provide reproducible example. You also can use `type` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to declare a standalone `interface` (although there's nothing wrong with it - it doesn't cost you anything!), you can use an inline type literal instead:

```
const AuctionCardGenerator = ({ auction }: { auction: randomAuctionType; }) => {
...
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. thank you